What Topologies Can Be Realized Using a Closed Base of Compact Sets
Given an arbitrary topological space $(X,\tau)$, note that the union of two compact sets is always compact, although the intersection of compact sets need not be compact.
So we can create a new topology $\tau'$ using the $\tau$-compact sets as a base of closed sets. Specifically, a set is closed in $\tau'$ if it is $X$ or the intersection of some nonempty family of sets which are compact in $\tau$.
How can we characterize the topologies $(X,\tau')$ created using this procedure?
Some easy things I've noted:

It is a necessary condition that $\tau'$ is $T_1$ because every singleton is easily compact in $\tau$ and thus closed in $\tau'$.
If $\tau$ is compact Hausdorff then every closed set in $\tau$ is compact, and vice versa. So $\tau' = \tau$ and can be generated in this way.

A few examples:

If $(X,\tau)$ is the discrete topology, $\tau'$ seems to be the cofinite topology because only finite sets are compact in a discrete space. So $\tau''$ is the discrete topology again because every set is compact in a cofinite topology.
Likewise, starting with $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ the standard topology, we have $C$ is closed in $\tau'$ if it is closed and bounded in $\tau$. Then I believe that any $\tau$-closed subset will actually be compact in $\tau'$, so $\tau'' \supseteq \tau$. I'm not sure if equality holds, though.


For the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, you do have $\tau’’ = \tau$. Indeed, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not closed under $\tau$, then there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which is in the closure of $A$ under $\tau$ but not in $A$. Then $[x - 1/n, x + 1/n]$, which is closed in $\tau’$, intersects with $A$ for all $n$ but the decreasing infinite intersection of all $[x - 1/n, x + 1/n]$ does not intersect with $A$, showing that $A$ is not compact in $\tau’$. So compact sets in $\tau’$ are exactly closed sets in $\tau$, so $\tau’’ = \tau$.

Basically the same argument shows, whenever $\tau$ is locally compact Hausdorff, we have $\tau’’ = \tau$.

This is by no means a complete answer, but it is a very interesting duality theorem that characterizes a large class of topologies created through this procedure.
Definition: We say a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is dual to locally compact Hausdorff (DLCH) if it satisfies the following properties:

$X$ is $T_1$;
$X$ is compact;
$X$ is locally compact, i.e., every point in $x$ has a local neighborhood basis of compact sets (note that local compactness, under this definition, does not follow from compactness without assuming the space is Hausdorff);
Closed proper subsets of $X$ satisfy the finite intersection property for compact subsets, i.e., if $A \subsetneq X$ is closed and $K_i \subset X$ is a collection of compact subsets s.t. $A \cap (\bigcap_{i \in I} K_i) = \varnothing$, then there is a finite subcollection $I_0 \subset I$ s.t. $A \cap (\bigcap_{i \in I_0} K_i) = \varnothing$.

Example: All compact Hausdorff spaces are DLCH. They are also locally compact Hausdorff (LCH). Co-finite topology on any set is always DLCH.
Theorem: Let $(X, \tau)$ be a LCH space. Then $\tau’$ is DLCH and $\tau’’ = \tau$. Dually, if $(X, \tau)$ is DLCH, then $\tau’$ is LCH and $\tau’’ = \tau$.
Proof: We begin with $(X, \tau)$ being LCH. First, if $A \subset X$ is $\tau$-closed, then we claim that it is $\tau’$-compact. Indeed, as compact sets in a Hausdorff space are closed under arbitrary intersections, $\tau’$-closed sets are exactly $X$ and $\tau$-compact sets. So as $A$ is $\tau$-closed and $\tau$ is Hausdorff, $A$ has the finite intersection property for $\tau$-compact sets, or equivalently, it has the finite intersection property for $\tau’$-closed sets, which precisely means it is $\tau’$-compact.
Conversely, if $A \subset X$ is not $\tau$-closed, then we claim that it is not $\tau’$-compact. Indeed, pick some $x \in \overline{A}^\tau \setminus A$. As $\tau$ is locally compact, there is a local $\tau$-neighborhood basis $\{K_i\}$ of $x$ consisting of $\tau$-compact sets. Since $\tau$ is Hausdorff, $\bigcap_i K_i = \{x\}$, so $A \cap (\bigcap_i K_i) = \varnothing$. But then, as $x \in \overline{A}^\tau$ and each $K_i$ is a $\tau$-neighborhood of $x$, we have $A \cap K_{i_1} \cap \cdots \cap K_{i_n} \neq \varnothing$ for any finitely many $K_{i_1}, \cdots, K_{i_n}$. This shows $A$ fails the finite intersection property for $\tau$-compact sets, equivalently $\tau’$-closed sets, whence $A$ is not $\tau’$-compact.
This shows $A \subset X$ is $\tau’$-compact iff it is $\tau$-closed, from which we easily see that $\tau’’ = \tau$.
Now, onto showing $\tau’$ is DLCH. Since singletons are always compact, $\tau’$ is clearly $T_1$. To show it is compact, we note that $X$ is clearly $\tau$-closed in itself, so it is $\tau’$-compact. To show it is locally compact, let $x \in U$ where $U \subset X$ is $\tau’$-open. Since $X \setminus U$ is then a proper subset of $X$ that is $\tau’$-closed, it must be $\tau$-compact. As $\tau$ is LCH, for each $y \in X \setminus U$, there exists a $\tau$-open neighborhood $V_y$ of $y$ s.t. $\overline{V_y}^\tau$ is $\tau$-compact and does not contain $x$. $\{V_y\}_{y \in X \setminus U}$ is a $\tau$-open cover of the $\tau$-compact set $X \setminus U$, so there is a finite subcover $\{V_{y_1}, \cdots, V_{y_n}\}$. Thus, $V = \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{y_i}$ is a $\tau$-open neighborhood of $X \setminus U$ s.t. $\overline{V}^\tau$ is $\tau$-compact and does not contain $x$. Translating this into $\tau’$, we see that $X \setminus V$ is then a subset of $U$ that is $\tau$-closed and thus $\tau’$-compact. Furthermore, it contains a subset $X \setminus \overline{V}^\tau$ that contains $x$ and is $\tau$-co-compact, so $\tau’$-open, i.e., $X \setminus V$ is a $\tau’$-compact neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $U$. This shows $\tau’$ is locally compact.
Finally, for condition $4$ in the definition of DLCH, $\tau’$-closed proper subsets of $X$ are exactly $\tau$-compact sets, and $\tau’$-compact sets are exactly $\tau$-closed sets, so we just need to show $\tau$-compact sets have the finite intersection property for $\tau$-closed sets, which is just the definition of compactness.
Now, for the second half, assume $(X, \tau)$ is DLCH. We start by showing $\tau’$ is Hausdorff. Indeed, let $x, y \in X$, $x \neq y$. Dualizing the definition of Hausdorff spaces to using closed sets, we see that we need to show there exist $\tau’$-closed sets $A, B \subset X$ s.t. $x \notin A$, $y \notin B$, and $A \cup B = X$. Since $\tau$ is $T_1$ and locally compact, there exists a $\tau$-compact neighborhood $B$ of $x$ that does not contain $y$. By definition, $B$ is $\tau’$-closed. The $\tau$-interior of $B$ contains $x$, so we may let $A$ be the complement of the $\tau$-interior of $B$ and then we have $x \notin A$. Moreover, $A$ is $\tau$-closed and thus also $\tau$-compact as $\tau$ is compact, whence $A$ is $\tau’$-closed. This shows $\tau’$ is Hausdorff.
To show it is locally compact, let $x \in X$. We need to show there is a $\tau’$-compact neighborhood of $x$. If $X = \{x\}$, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we may choose $y \in X$ s.t. $y \neq x$. By local compactness of $\tau$, there is a $\tau$-compact neighborhood $U$ of $y$ with $x \notin U$. Let $V$ be the $\tau$-interior of $U$, which still contains $y$ and still does not contain $x$. Then $X \setminus V$ is $\tau$-closed and, as it does not contain $y$, a proper subset of $X$, so by condition $4$ of the definition of DLCH, it has the finite intersection property for $\tau$-compact sets. But $\tau$-compact sets form a closed basis for $\tau’$, so this is enough to show $X \setminus V$ is $\tau’$-compact. Moreover, $x \in X \setminus U \subset X \setminus V$, and, as $U$ is $\tau$-compact, $X \setminus U$ is $\tau$-co-compact so $\tau’$-open, i.e., $X \setminus V$ is a $\tau’$-compact neighborhood of $x$. This shows $\tau’$ is locally compact.
As we have already observed in the preceding paragraph, any $\tau$-closed proper subset of $X$ is automatically $\tau’$-compact. Conversely, if $A \subset X$ is not $\tau$-closed, then we claim it is not $\tau’$-compact. The proof is essentially the same as the LCH case. Again, pick some $x \in \overline{A}^\tau \setminus A$. As $\tau$ is locally compact, there is a local $\tau$-neighborhood basis $\{K_i\}$ of $x$ consisting of $\tau$-compact sets. Since $\tau$ is $T_1$, $\bigcap_i K_i = \{x\}$, so $A \cap (\bigcap_i K_i) = \varnothing$. But then, as $x \in \overline{A}^\tau$ and each $K_i$ is a $\tau$-neighborhood of $x$, we have $A \cap K_{i_1} \cap \cdots \cap K_{i_n} \neq \varnothing$ for any finitely many $K_{i_1}, \cdots, K_{i_n}$. This shows $A$ fails the finite intersection property for $\tau$-compact sets, so it fails the finite intersection property for $\tau’$-closed sets as well, whence $A$ is not $\tau’$-compact.
This shows $\tau’$-compact sets are exactly $\tau$-closed sets, with the possible exception of $X$ itself. From this, it is immediate that $\tau’’ = \tau$. $\square$
Remark: In particular, all LCH and DLCH spaces arise out of this procedure. It is also interesting to note that the proof of the duality theorem implies compact sets in a DLCH space are exactly closed sets in its dual space, so despite not listed as an axiom for DLCH spaces, and despite them not necessarily being KC spaces (spaces in which all compact sets are closed) - as an example, cofinite topology on an infinite set is DLCH but not KC - they do satisfy the condition that arbitrary intersections of compact sets are automatically compact.

Remark: We also have the result that the topological spaces $(X, \tau)$ for which $\tau = \tau’$ are exactly compact KC spaces. Indeed, $\tau’ \subset \tau$ implies $\tau$ is KC. But then arbitrary intersections of $\tau$-compact sets are easily seen to be $\tau$-compact, so $\tau \subset \tau’$ implies $\tau$-closed proper subsets of $X$ must be $\tau$-compact. By directly applying the definition of compactness, it is not hard to see this implies $X$ itself must be $\tau$-compact as well. Conversely, compactness and KC together imply closed sets and compact sets coincide, so $\tau = \tau’$. Now, if we require local compactness, then this only happens iff $(X, \tau)$ is compact Hausdorff. Indeed, singletons are compact, so KC implies $X$ is $T_1$. But then, local compactness together with KC implies each point has a local neighborhood basis of closed sets, which, as $X$ is $T_1$, implies it must be Hausdorff. However, this description does mean there are non-locally compact spaces that are self-dual (and thus in particular can be obtained through this procedure, despite not being subject to the duality theorem). Indeed, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Q}$ is compact and KC, so it is self-dual. But it is not Hausdorff, so neither is it locally compact.

Incredible answer! I'll need to take a detailed look at this later.
